# Looping over on array inside a React component defined as a class

Tags: arrays, reactjs, babeljs, react-component

I'm trying to loop over an array (selectedItem.stats) that is passed as a prop to the component.

I've seen some examples online, but all none of them when the component is defined as a class.

I figured I'd put the loop inside the render function, above the return, but this doesn't seem to work. How should I go about this?

I get `stats is undefined`.

Here's my code:

```
class ItemDetails extends Component {

  render() {

    let stats = this.props.selectedItem.stats.map((item, key) =>
        <li><span className="stat-label">{item.name}</span><span className="stat-value">{item.value}</span></li>
    );

    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.selectedItem ? (
          <div id="item-details">
            <div id="item-stats" className="col">
              <h4>Stats</h4>
              <ul>{stats}</ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        ) : (
         <p>No Item selected</p>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ItemDetails;
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the value that you get as props of the component may not have all the fields. So, when you try to access `name` and `value` attribute of `item`, those values could be empty and hence did not show up in the bulleted list.

Following is the code which worked for me:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const selectedItem = { stats: [{ name: 'name1', value: 'value1' }, { name: 'name2', value: 'value2' }]};

class ItemDetails extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let stats = this.props.selectedItem.stats.map((item, key) => (
      <li key={key}>
        <span className="stat-label">{item.name}</span>
        <span className="stat-value">{item.value}</span>
      </li>
    ));

    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.selectedItem ? (
          <div id="item-details">
            <div id="item-stats" className="col">
              <h4>Stats</h4>
              <ul>{stats}</ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <p>No Item selected</p>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<ItemDetails selectedItem={selectedItem} />, rootElement);
```

Here, `const selectedItem = { stats: [{ name: 'name1', value: 'value1' }, { name: 'name2', value: 'value2' }]};` is the prop that the component `ItemDetails` receives. Make sure that your prop has all the fields that you are trying to access  in the component and it should work.